# How do I find individuals that are participants in multiple (two) events?

Tags: civievent, search, participants

I want to see who is registered for both of two events. How can I do that as a search or a report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Search, Participant Search And reports only allows you to select 'One of' the selected option i.e it does "Event 1 OR Event 2" on the selected events.

But I guess you want "Event 1 AND Event 2", if so you can use CiviCRM >> Search >> Search Builder to do AND between conditions. See below attached image
[image]

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Although it's a minor hassle to figure out the IDs of the events, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately its a core bug, it should show drop down list with event.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this always works. I have an Individual that I *know* is a participant of two events, but with different roles, but the above search does not return this individual.

Comment: Im pretty sure this isnt working.. 1 event is fine.. any more and you get nil results: see  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/35676/189

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in multiple steps:

- search for Event 1 participants then create a group
- use advanced search, enter the new group in the group box, and in the events section select Event 2 participants

You could create both of those as smart groups if you want to check progress as registrations come in.

But hopefully someone has a more streamlined method!

Comment: I always forget about this ”best practice” for more advanced searches.