# Search builder - Cant find find Participants in more than one event

Tags: search-builder, participants

Im trying to find people who have attended all 3 of our last 3 annual fund raising dinners.

- search for participants in "dinner 2018" - get results
- search for participants  in "dinner 2019" - get results

Search for participants "dinner 2018" AND "dinner 2019" - get zero  (and that's wrong cause I'm one of many who are showing as having been to both)

The same error occurs using event ID

I cant get the event start date to return sensible answers (not sure whats going on there  tbh)

I know I can get the correct answer using groups but thats adding another step in the process each year and Id rather avoid that

any suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of search criteria?

Comment: screenshot added, thanks

Comment: create a Group of each sets of Participants and then try using those via Search Builder?

Comment: that will certainly give an answer but as I said I was hoping to avoid this extra step.. everything else works fine in Search Builder - just cant seem to get participants working?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this this way because a single participant record is never going to match both at the same time, i.e. something like `SELECT id FROM civicrm_participant WHERE event_id = 1 AND event_id = 2` is always false. The same way e.g. you wouldn't be able to use this to find people who made contributions of both $100 and $200. As noted you probably need to do something like use groups.

Comment: ah..great answer,  makes perfect sense... thanks very much for your help

Comment: Or change the search builder so that you are effectively using 'OR'.  The way you have it's using 'AND'. So search bulder could certainly do this by using 'also include contacts where' part rather than 'Another search field'

Comment: but OR will give the wrong answer.. I want people who have been to both, not to either?